# How to update tkinter message

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a string variable called "spe" in a tk.message that I want it to change after the execution of Identify

```
Add after changing of `spe_win`:
```

```
spe.set(spe_win)
```

I think you can throw out `spe_win` variable and use `spe.set("Updated ...")` instead.

Edit after discussion in comments below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
global spe="Number"
class IdPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        tk.Button.__init__(self,parent)
        tk.Message.__init__(self,parent)
        tk.Label.__init__(self,parent)
        speak = tk.StringVar(self)
        record_identify = tk.Button(self,
            text = "Record/Identifies",
            font = ("Arial",15),
            command = self.Identify)
        speak = tk.Message(self,
            textvariable = spe,
            width=250)
        spe.set(spe)
        speak.pack()
        record_identify.pack()

global spe="Number"
def Identify():
        print("Your favourite number:")
        a=input()
        if a>5:
            spe="Updated positive"
        else:
            spe="Updated Negative"

root = tk.Tk()
frame = IdPage(root)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Add after changing of `spe_win`:

```
spe.set(spe_win)
```

I think you can throw out `spe_win` variable and use `spe.set("Updated ...")` instead.

Edit after discussion in comments below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class IdPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        tk.Button.__init__(self,parent)
        tk.Message.__init__(self,parent)
        tk.Label.__init__(self,parent)
        self.spe = tk.StringVar(self)
        record_identify = tk.Button(self,
            text = "Record/Identifies",
            font = ("Arial",15),
            command = lambda: Identify(self.spe))
        speak = tk.Message(self,
            textvariable = self.spe,
            width=250)
        self.spe.set("How're you?")
        speak.pack()
        record_identify.pack()

def Identify(spe):
    a=4
    if a>3:
        spe.set("Updated positive")
    else:
        spe.set("Updated Negative")

root = tk.Tk()
frame = IdPage(root)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The function identify does some maths that's how 'spe_win' gets its value....I just didn't put the whole identify function maths process in the example above

Comment: So you can use it but when you want to update text in `tk.Message`, just use `spe.set()` function.

Comment: If I helped you, you can vote up this answer and mark it as a solution because I'm trying to gain some reputation.

Comment: Could you provide more code? That I would be able to copy it and execute on my machine... Maybe you've got some problem with scopes or something like that.

Comment: I've tested this on my own and it's working. Try to analyze this code. See the edited answer.

Comment: function identify is not under the class Idpage. Its different from class Idpage

Comment: Ok, but I think using globals isn't the best practice.

Comment: how can I return the string from the function Idpage to the tk.label to update

Comment: You can make some function in `IdPage` class which will be setting the value of `spe`. Then change a command of `record_identify` to `lambda: self.set(Identify())`. Where `set` is a name of that function.

Comment: I edited the answer that there isn't Identify in `IdPage`. You can analyze it. Can I help you with anything else?